# pygame / ALSA error on colab when rendering

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, google-colaboratory, alsa

I am trying to run a script in colab that rendering a latent vector interpolation (reference github: https://github.com/marian42/shapegan

scroll to the last section --> Using the pretrained DeepSDF model and recreating the latent space traversal animation

After following all steps and running !python3 demo_latent_space.py , I am getting this error on colab. I appreciate all feedback:

```
Calculating embedding...
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sklearn/manifold/_t_sne.py:780: FutureWarning: The default initialization in TSNE will change from 'random' to 'pca' in 1.2.
  warnings.warn(
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sklearn/manifold/_t_sne.py:790: FutureWarning: The default learning rate in TSNE will change from 200.0 to 'auto' in 1.2.
  warnings.warn(
Calculating clusters...
Calculating trip...
100% 100/100 [00:20<00:00,  4.95it/s]
Rendering...
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo_latent_space.py", line 160, in <module>
    viewer = MeshRenderer(size=1080, start_thread=False)
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/EnactiveDesign/final-project/grayboxAI/shapegan/rendering/__init__.py", line 91, in __init__
    self._initialize_opengl()
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/EnactiveDesign/final-project/grayboxAI/shapegan/rendering/__init__.py", line 264, in _initialize_opengl
    pygame.display.gl_set_attribute(pygame.GL_MULTISAMPLEBUFFERS, 1)
pygame.error: video system not initialized
```

This is the demo_latent_space.py -->

```
from util import device, ensure_directory
import scipy.interpolate
import numpy as np
from rendering import MeshRenderer
import torch
from tqdm import tqdm
import cv2
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
from matplotlib.offsetbox import Bbox
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

SAMPLE_COUNT = 30 # Number of distinct objects to generate and interpolate between
TRANSITION_FRAMES = 60

USE_VAE = False

SURFACE_LEVEL = 0.011

FRAMES = SAMPLE_COUNT * TRANSITION_FRAMES
progress = np.arange(FRAMES, dtype=float) / TRANSITION_FRAMES


if USE_VAE:
    from model.autoencoder import Autoencoder, LATENT_CODE_SIZE
    vae = Autoencoder()
    vae.load()
    vae.eval()
    print("Calculating latent codes...")


    from datasets import VoxelDataset
    from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

    dataset = VoxelDataset.glob('data/chairs/voxels_32/**.npy')
    dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=1000, num_workers=8)

    latent_codes = torch.zeros((len(dataset), LATENT_CODE_SIZE))

    with torch.no_grad():
        position = 0
        for batch in tqdm(dataloader):
            latent_codes[position:position + batch.shape[0], :] = vae.encode(batch.to(device)).detach().cpu()
    latent_codes = latent_codes.numpy()
else:
    from model.sdf_net import SDFNet, LATENT_CODES_FILENAME
    latent_codes = torch.load(LATENT_CODES_FILENAME).detach().cpu().numpy()

    sdf_net = SDFNet()
    sdf_net.load()
    sdf_net.eval()

from shapenet_metadata import shapenet
labels = torch.load('data/labels.to')

print("Calculating embedding...")
tsne = TSNE(n_components=2)
latent_codes_embedded = tsne.fit_transform(latent_codes)
print("Calculating clusters...")
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=SAMPLE_COUNT)

indices = np.zeros(SAMPLE_COUNT, dtype=int)
kmeans_clusters = kmeans.fit_predict(latent_codes_embedded)
for i in range(SAMPLE_COUNT):
    center = kmeans.cluster_centers_[i, :]
    cluster_classes = labels[kmeans_clusters == i]
    cluster_class = np.bincount(cluster_classes).argmax()
    dist = np.linalg.norm(latent_codes_embedded - center[np.newaxis, :], axis=1)
    dist[labels != cluster_class] = float('inf')
    indices[i] = np.argmin(dist)

def try_find_shortest_roundtrip(indices):
    best_order = indices
    best_distance = None
    for _ in range(5000):
        candiate = best_order.copy()
        a = random.randint(0, SAMPLE_COUNT-1)
        b = random.randint(0, SAMPLE_COUNT-1)
        candiate[a] = best_order[b]
        candiate[b] = best_order[a]
        dist = np.sum(np.linalg.norm(latent_codes_embedded[candiate, :] - latent_codes_embedded[np.roll(candiate, 1), :], axis=1)).item()
        if best_distance is None or dist < best_distance:
            best_distance = dist
            best_order = candiate

    return best_order, best_distance

def find_shortest_roundtrip(indices):
    best_order, best_distance = try_find_shortest_roundtrip(indices)

    for _ in tqdm(range(100)):
        np.random.shuffle(indices)
        order, distance = try_find_shortest_roundtrip(indices)
        if distance < best_distance:
            best_order = order
    return best_order

print("Calculating trip...")
indices = find_shortest_roundtrip(indices)
indices = np.concatenate((indices, indices[0][np.newaxis]))

SIZE = latent_codes.shape[0]

stop_latent_codes = latent_codes[indices, :]

colors = np.zeros((labels.shape[0], 3))
for i in range(labels.shape[0]):
    colors[i, :] = shapenet.get_color(labels[i])

spline = scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline(np.arange(SAMPLE_COUNT + 1), stop_latent_codes, axis=0, bc_type='periodic')
frame_latent_codes = spline(progress)

color_spline = scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline(np.arange(SAMPLE_COUNT + 1), colors[indices, :], axis=0, bc_type='periodic')
frame_colors = color_spline(progress)
frame_colors = np.clip(frame_colors, 0, 1)

frame_colors = np.zeros((progress.shape[0], 3))
for i in range(SAMPLE_COUNT):
    frame_colors[i*TRANSITION_FRAMES:(i+1)*TRANSITION_FRAMES, :] = np.linspace(colors[indices[i]], colors[indices[i+1]], num=TRANSITION_FRAMES)

embedded_spline = scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline(np.arange(SAMPLE_COUNT + 1), latent_codes_embedded[indices, :], axis=0, bc_type='periodic')
frame_latent_codes_embedded = embedded_spline(progress)
frame_latent_codes_embedded[0, :] = frame_latent_codes_embedded[-1, :]

width, height = 40, 40

PLOT_FILE_NAME = 'tsne.png'
ensure_directory('images')

margin = 2
range_x = (latent_codes_embedded[:, 0].min() - margin, latent_codes_embedded[:, 0].max() + margin)
range_y = (latent_codes_embedded[:, 1].min() - margin, latent_codes_embedded[:, 1].max() + margin)

plt.ioff()

def create_plot(index, resolution=1080, filename=PLOT_FILE_NAME, dpi=100):
    frame_color = frame_colors[index, :]
    frame_color = (frame_color[0], frame_color[1], frame_color[2], 1.0)

    size_inches = resolution / dpi

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(size_inches, size_inches), dpi=dpi)
    ax.set_position([0, 0, 1, 1])
    plt.axis('off')
    ax.set_xlim(range_x)
    ax.set_ylim(range_y)

    ax.plot(frame_latent_codes_embedded[:, 0], frame_latent_codes_embedded[:, 1], c=(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0), zorder=1, linewidth=2)
    ax.scatter(latent_codes_embedded[:, 0], latent_codes_embedded[:, 1], c=colors[:SIZE], s = 10, zorder=0)
    ax.scatter(frame_latent_codes_embedded[index, 0], frame_latent_codes_embedded[index, 1], facecolors=frame_color, s = 200, linewidths=2, edgecolors=(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0), zorder=2)
    ax.scatter(latent_codes_embedded[indices, 0], latent_codes_embedded[indices, 1], facecolors=colors[indices, :], s = 140, linewidths=1, edgecolors=(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0), zorder=3)
    
    fig.savefig(filename, bbox_inches=Bbox([[0, 0], [size_inches, size_inches]]), dpi=dpi)
    plt.close(fig)

frame_latent_codes = torch.tensor(frame_latent_codes, dtype=torch.float32, device=device)

print("Rendering...")
viewer = MeshRenderer(size=1080, start_thread=False)

def render_frame(frame_index):
    viewer.model_color = frame_colors[frame_index, :]
    with torch.no_grad():
        if USE_VAE:
            viewer.set_voxels(vae.decode(frame_latent_codes[frame_index, :]))
        else:
            viewer.set_mesh(sdf_net.get_mesh(frame_latent_codes[frame_index, :], voxel_resolution=128, sphere_only=True, level=SURFACE_LEVEL))
    image_mesh = viewer.get_image(flip_red_blue=True)

    create_plot(frame_index)
    image_tsne = plt.imread(PLOT_FILE_NAME)[:, :, [2, 1, 0]] * 255

    image = np.concatenate((image_mesh, image_tsne), axis=1)

    cv2.imwrite("images/frame-{:05d}.png".format(frame_index), image)


for frame_index in tqdm(range(SAMPLE_COUNT * TRANSITION_FRAMES)):
    render_frame(frame_index)
    frame_index += 1

print("\n\nUse this command to create a video:\n")
print('ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i images/frame-%05d.png -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -crf 19 -pix_fmt yuv420p video.mp4')
```

Comment: This appears to be a script that can only be run locally, with access to your video card and sound output, rather than on a remote server like Colab.

Comment: Thanks jason. Much appreciated.

May I follow up with another question?
Is this something I can change?
Alternatively, can I eliminate the "rendering" / visualization part? I just want to sample from the latent space some models and download them into gDrive, no need for images actually. I tried editing the code and I have a sampleGAN function but did not get it to work